# Menu dropdown for the navigationbar is not opening

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add a dropdown menu to my navbar but it doesn't work. The menu button just does not drop down the menu.

Also the profile picture and name ends up in the middle instead of to the right.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-xxl">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img class="d-inline-blockp" src="" alt="" width="40"
                height="40" />
            Left
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="" alt="profile picture" width="40"
                height="40" />
            Name
        </a>
        <div class="">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#hamburger"
                aria-controls="hamburger" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hamburger">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menubutton isn't working because you haven't included bootstrap starter script in your html file.

**Include the script in your head tag or inside body tag**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```